# Connecting putty (or plink) to DaHaus

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

For school we need to build a webinterface which interacts with the program DaHaus (a sort of autonomation program).

As of now I first made contact simply with `putty` and that worked.

However I found out that I couldn't make that connection automated since `putty` had an UI.

Then I tried `plink` which could connect to the program but once it did I couldn't type a single thing.

How to connect: telnet with port number 11000 and localhost or 127.0.0.1

I am wondering if its possible to make `plink` do the commands in a way that works or how to do it with `putty` without the shell since it needs to be automated.

Also the code we need to make it in is `c#` with `visual studio` in `asp.net`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I formatted your question - I had hope that I will understand your question after that. Please check my corrections. I'm still find it's hard for me to understand your problem: a) is it question about `plink`/`putty`/"automation thru telnet"? b) if it's a `c#` question - can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: i've solved it on my own the solution was to use an online library on https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library

using this library you can set up a telnet connection with whatever program you want. For using it inside a project simply copy the telnetinferface.cs file to the correct folder inside your project.

within your code simply state using TelnetInterface;